# Android-Studio refresh project with build.gradle changes

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

how can I sync changes I made in the build.gradle into the project structure ( e.g. that AndroidStudio is recognizing the lib I added?
Kind of like the "reimport all maven projects" for maven projects - just for a pure gradle project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<strike>I read somewhere that the "Synchronize" item on the module's context menu should update the IDE's settings based on the build.gradle file.</strike>

Ok, so in the latest version of Android Studio 0.1.3, they've added a Gradle project refresh button next to the other Android specific buttons in the toolbar. Make changes manually to the build.gradle files and settings.gradle and then click this button. It should configure and refresh your project settings based on the gradle files.

Comment: Go to preferences, search for "gradle", then verify that auto build is checked. Sorry if that's not the exact name, I'm writing this from my phone.

Comment: this is checked - still not working for me :-( but thanks for the follow up!

Comment: Yea, I've had to manually modify the project structure. Adding facets to the modules isn't even always consistent. Compare the .iml files for a new project and manually created one. Wrote about it at nicknackhacks.org. Sorry I wasn't able to help. In the same boat it seems.

Comment: seems to be very little humans in this boat at the moment ;-) But thanks for bearing with me ..

Comment: There are a lot of bugs here... In some cases, to refresh the project structure I am deleting the .idea and .iml files and importing the project again into AS with the gradle importer

Comment: Yup, restarting seems to work for me. I read something recently about the settings.gradle being honored to update the project structure, but that the build.gradle files weren't actually connected yet. Eventually modifications through the GUI will edit the build.gradle files automatically. For now they disabled the GUI in AS 0.1.1

Comment: @GrkEngineer  ~"Go to preferences, search for "gradle", then verify that auto build is checked."  There is no such a thing in Android Studio 0.4.0.

Answer (score 10):

One thing that has worked for me was opening the Gradle panel on the right side of the editor (above "Maven Projects" and "Commander") and clicking the refresh button. That refreshed the module settings.

Comment: I don't see that window for some reason.

Comment: @nmr try clicking on the square icon in the bottom left corner. That will make side menus appear.

Comment: Turns out the Gradle window and the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button are both hidden when Android Studio is running in (legacy) IntelliJ project mode.

There's a related Android bug here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56373

Comment: You can also open the Gradle panel by doing View | Tool Windows | Gradle. (I'm using Android Studio 0.2.9)

Comment: ~"opening the Gradle panel on the right side".  I don't even get that panel.  No matter if I click 'View -> Tool Windows'.  If Android Studio doesn't recognize your project as a Gradle-based project, then there is nothing you can do.  Period.

Answer (score 3):

For **Android Studio 4.1.2** click on the button pointed on picture

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My solution for newer version of Android Studio. Tested on version 3.2.1. You can selected Refresh from the menu as showing here:
[image]