# Android LibGDX 'Cannot resolve symbol setRadius'

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm using Box2d, libGDX and have imported ...physics.box2d.CircleShape; what did I do wrong such that setRadius isn't acceptable. Thanks for your time.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Shape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder;
import sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.Constants;
```

I'm trying to follow the Github tutorial. I checked the API guide and I followed the function rules. It's not suggesting any more imports.

[image]

Comment: Seems alright to me. Did you already try to refresh-all gradle? Which libGDX version do you use?

Comment: @donfuxx libGDX 1.6, and I'm not sure what you mean by refresh-all gradle. If it helps I tried rebuild, clean, and synchronize projects. Thanks

Comment: are you sure you import import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape; ? I wonder cause of the different syntax colors.

Comment: OK everybody I am truly sorry but I fixed the problem very stupidly. As it turns out I needed to put those to lines in the create() function. I forgot that it was a class and I put compiler instructions inside the class but outside of a function. This is all my bad, I am not yet used to working in Java and I tend to think everything is encased in a main program. If need be I'll remove this question because it's not good enough for stackoverflow but depending on what you guys think I may or may not leave this up for other people who experience this same thought. I'm sorry, thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm glad we solve the other hand, I think the question is not bad, what happens is that your mistake makes her look stupid, It makes it seem stupid to question, but who has not had stupid mistakes, the question is generally a mistake sule happen, and the answer I think are successful and can help another.I hope to explain well, I'm not calling you stupid. For future occasions Might put the stack trace of the error. bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moral of the story: put instructions inside of a function. Don't put them in the class like it's a variable. Sorry it took me over an hour to figure out how stupid I was being. No language I know even allows that even with constructors I'm sorry I will reRTFM. Thanks for putting up with this, I did learn some stuff from all your suggestions. If need be I'll edit/remove the question.

```
@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    // Initiate Sprite
    img = new Texture("heavybreathing.jpg");
    sprite = new Sprite(img);
    Red = new Sprite(new Texture("Red.png"));

    screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

    font = new BitmapFont();
    font.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    font.getData().scale(5);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);


    CircleShape circle1 = new CircleShape();
    circle1.setRadius(6f);

}
```

Comment: You didn`t show us the hole code ;) So we couldn`t guess the reason .

Answer (score 1):

Try to refresh all the dependencies of gradle . I think you use Android Studio . [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624056/android-studio-refresh-project-with-build-gradle-changes) is how to refresh with it.

If you use Eclipse -> Right Click on the project ->Gradle -> Refresh all.

Comment: I use android studio, but unfortunately it didn't change anything. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

The Box2d natives, are loaded in the code, to create world class, you have to have them loaded, before using, or also can use box2d.init (), my English is very bad you can read Here:

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/package-summary.html

P.S: I do not remember very well what was the error, and I can not look now but I think this will help

New:

```
resulting this error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape.newCircleShape()J
at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape.newCircleShape(Native Method)
at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape.(CircleShape.java:30)
```

just look for the network now, and if you are having something like this mistake, I think it should load, box2d before the World crearcion or box2d.init () are with; before using classes.

the error is confirmed, in this thread, I do not remember what it was, but he had had presenset that loaded before ->
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2393

Comment: I tried to create a world class, but the problem didn't go away. Also it threw up a lot of errors adding `new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true);`